# Ggplot() graph issues when creating stripped graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am creating graphs below based on data that I simulated. The data consists of two groups, A and B, each with different values drawn from different distributions. When I use the code below to create a stripplot graph, the range of the color scale changes for each simulated graph. For example, dark red for the top image maps to 90 compared to 120 in the bottom image. I need the colors to map to the same values throughout the creating of all of the graphs.

```
    ## GGPLOT: Ensemble Stripplts ##
            for(i in 1:max(unique(saveDT$iter))){
              
              #grab the data for this dataset
              gg<-saveDT[which(saveDT$iter==i),]
              gg$group<-factor(gg$group)
              
              # set the limits of the palette so that zero is in the middle of the range.

               # png(paste0("aggIndividGroupV1","-",sa,".png"), width = 400, height = 300)
               # par(mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
              print(ggplot(gg, aes(x=i, y=1,fill=value)) + facet_grid(. ~ group)+
                    theme(strip.background = element_rect(color="white", fill="white"))+
                    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = value, lwd=5, color=value))+
                    scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(9,"RdBu"))))
           }
```

Q1: How do I fix the color scale?

Q2: How can I change the midpoint value to represent a specific fixed midpoint?

Q3: Why does ggplot() make the RdBu brewer color palette look significantly different than when using RdBu in the plot() function? (see last image for comparison). Plot() seems to make them look more saturated and less of a gradient. I've tried to use the code scale_fill_divergentx() but this and other types do not work with my ggplot() function.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the limits of the colour scale with `limits` within `scale_colour_gradientn`. This also fixes the midpoint. Here I set the limits from 40 to 120, meaning the midpoint is 80.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: replacing previous import 'vctrs::data_frame' by 'tibble::data_frame'
#> when loading 'dplyr'
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(4)
gg <- data.frame(value = runif(20, min = 40, max = 120),
                 group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10))

print(ggplot(gg, aes(y=1, fill=value)) + facet_grid(. ~ group)+
        theme(strip.background = element_rect(color="white", fill="white"))+
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = value, color=value), size = 5)+
        scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(9,"RdBu")),
                               limits = c(40, 120)))
```

[image]

```r
gg <- data.frame(value = runif(20, min = 60, max = 80),
                 group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10))

print(ggplot(gg, aes(y=1,fill=value)) + facet_grid(. ~ group)+
        theme(strip.background = element_rect(color="white", fill="white"))+
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = value, color=value), size = 5)+
        scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(9,"RdBu")),
                               limits = c(40, 120)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Thanks **@Rui Barradas** for the improvements!

Comment: Upvote but 1) there's no need for `x=i`; 2) remove the `lwd=5` from `aes()` and place it right outside of it; 3)and call `lwd` (base graphics) the ggplot name, `size`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for the suggestions, you're completely right; I was too lazy and just copied OP's code

Comment: Thanks! So, I don't need to tell it the iteration in ggplot() because that is redundant information? If so, that makes sense to me now. Is there a way to remove all of the empty spaces between the strips so that they are adjacent to one another? These graphs will be presented without the values on the x-axis.

Comment: I basically want them to look similar to the #showyourstripes warming stripes graphs.

Comment: I think then the easiest way is to introduce an extra variable for the x-axis (e.g. just 1 to 10 in this case) for the ordering; however I haven't figured out yet how to minimise the spacing so that the lines are directly next to each other

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this @starja -- I was trying to use x=i to represent each iteration of the data that I simulated. But when I use x=i it doesn't seem to make the strips based on the number of iterations for each graph (each graph was iterated 100 times -- so each set/ensemble/iteration has 100 samples). I hope that makes sense.